# Connecting led IP65 strip from a wall socket to an adaptor/psu

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, adapter

I have no electrical background, so I have very basic knowledge about this, but this is what I can gather. So I'm trying to set up an led IP65 white strip, but I know that it needs certain components. Just to clarify, from the AC 220V wall socket, I have to connect it to the PSU/Adaptor (I have no idea which to use) first in order to change AC to DC, which then connects to the switch, then connects to the LED strip?

These are the lights I would like to use: [LEDs](http://www.ledsupply.com/led-strips/waterproof-12v-led-strip)

Requirements from the page: 12V, 7.4W per Meter.

Comment: Different strips will require different PSUs.  Post a link to the one you're using.

Comment: @user1850479 https://www.ledsupply.com/led-strips/waterproof-12v-led-strip 
this is the one I'll be using at length of 5 meters

Answer (score 0):

You need a 12v, constant voltage power supply.  The wattage depends on which model on that page you're using, but you'll need >36W or >72W, so a 50 or 100W supply would be reasonable.